# Samsung Galaxy Note 2 doesn't power on after changing Motion Settings

Tags: unbricking, samsung-galaxy-note-2, power-on

My wife want to use the side to side motion feature on her Samsung Galaxy Note 2 SCH-I605 (Verizon). I allowed the feature, but then her screen dimmed then went off. When I pushed the power button, nothing happens.

It had been getting hot near the motion sensor, so I replaced with a new one (before the shutdown happened) and everything was going fine. But it shutdown like I said earlier and won't come back on.

I can't enter any mode as it won't come on and it's unresponsive. I have purchased two OEM batteries, but it didn't help. I also used a new OEM charger but again, didn't fix. When I connect it to the computer or charger, nothing happened; no battery icon or LCD light.

The SKU is SCHI605ZWV if that helps. It's not rooted and has the official Android 4.4.2 update from Verizon.

My questions:

- Do I need a motherboard replacement or any peripherals replacement?
- Can a bad power button affect the charging process? (stop charging or stop showing the battery icon when charging)
- Can a bad USB charging port stop it from turning on?
- Can I have a list of possible things that would stop all functions from working and not turning on?

Comment: I'm afraid you have burnt the motherboard. You'd better go to Samsung service center to have it checked.